# Why happened out of bound error in for loop?

Tags: octave, indexoutofboundsexception

Out of bound error occured.

This is Octave language.

```
for ii=1:1:10
    m(ii)=ii*8
    q=m(ii)
    if (ii>=2)
        q(ii).xdot=(q(ii).x-q(ii-1).x)/Ts;
    end
end
```

But error says

```
 q(2): out of bound 1
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: what is `q` before the loop? you may need to initialize it

Comment: You say `q=m(ii)`, which means `q` gets assigned a scalar. Then you do `q(ii)`, which doesn't exist if `ii` is larger than 1, since `q` is a scalar. I think you might want to do `q(ii)=m(ii)` instead.

Comment: Yes, when changing to `q(ii)=m(ii)`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of assignment you do not need a loop and anyway you need to define `Ts`.
To calculate differential increase you can use `diff`

```
x=(1:1:10)*8
x =

    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80

octave:5> Ts=2
Ts =  2
octave:6> xdot=diff(x)/Ts
xdot =

   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4

octave:7> size(x)
ans =

    1   10

octave:8> size(xdot)
ans =

   1   9
```